# NodeJS, crypto.randomUUID is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, uuid

I'm very new to JS, I want to generate an UUID. Here's what I tried, step by step:

1. `mkdir test`
2. `cd test`
3. `touch file1.js`
4. Inside `file1.js`:

```html
let crypto;
try {
  crypto = require('crypto');
} catch (err) {
  console.log('crypto support is disabled!');
}


var uuid = crypto.randomUUID();
console.log(uuid);
```

And you see the error. What is wrong? I can't find answer anywhere. Node JS version:

`node -v` shows `v12.22.9`

[image]

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: When I run your code I get "847971d2-4a43-4744-a280-be9c6cfec4a7", meaning that it works. Double check your node version.

Comment: (Side note: Your code after the `try`/`catch` should be **inside** the `try`, since if crypto support is disabled, `crypto` will be `undefined` where you're trying to use it.)

Comment: The [`randomUUID`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptorandomuuidoptions) function was added in `Node v15.6.0`. You need to upgrade node.

Comment: Did you installed crypto? try `npm i crypto`

Comment: @MohamedEL-Gendy It's part of the node standard library, no need to install

Comment: @mousetail Your link states that it was "Added in: v15.6.0, v14.17.0", so it is also available in v14. For example, I'm on v14.20.0 and that function works fine...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

here you can use `randomBytes()` method for get unique id

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
console.log(crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex'));
```

you can also use uuidv4 instead of crypto

```
const { uuid } = require('uuidv4');
console.log(uuid());
```

Comment: crypto is built into node

Comment: Yes but this method is not supported to this node version(12.22.9)

Comment: DeprecationWarning: uuidv4() is deprecated. Use v4() from the uuid module instead.

Answer (score 9):

The error is that the `crypto.randomUUID` function was added for Node versions `> v14.17.0`.

That is according to the official docs: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptorandomuuidoptions

So probably your best choice, if you do not want to use newer Node versions, would be to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded NodeJS to newer version, and it worked!

I had some problems, so I tried to remove NodeJS (I had the same problem like this guy: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1157).

And installed LTS version: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265813/how-to-update-node-js-to-the-long-term-support-version-on-ubuntu-20-04.

Now I have:

> `node -v`
> `v16.16.0`

and script works! Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
const id = new Crypto().randomUUID();
```